# Como fazer Update de um campo usando ele ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: mysql, query, sql-update

Gostaria de saber se tem uma forma de somar o valor de um linha com ela mesma sem precisar fazer uma `query` depois um update.

Eu tenho uma coluna chamada `total` que guarda inteiros, em determinado momento quero que o valor que está nesta linha seja somando com um novo valor inserido, sem que seja necessário fazer uma query, somar com um novo valor e depois fazer o update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que é isso que você precisa:

```
update tabela set total = total+5
```

Comment: E eu complicando rs. Muito obrigado!!